# Failure to build unity game apk

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

everytime I try building the apk for my unity android game instead of getting the apk I get a file which is titled ‘NAMEOFGAME_BurstDebugInformation_DoNotShip’ how can I fix this and get the apk I wish to build?

I don’t know what to do to solve this problem

Comment: Can you please provide a screenshot of your build settings?

Comment: Unfortunately its not allowing me to post screenshots

Comment: Edit your answer and provide error info from the console, or the editor log (lookup Log files in unity manual for the path). As for the build settings, just tell us what checkboxes are ticked.

Answer (score 0):

After some research I found the below info:

The error "NAMEOFGAME_BurstDebugInformation_DoNotShip" in Unity is related to the Burst Compiler, which is a high-performance compiler for C# code that is used in Unity. This error occurs when the Burst Compiler is trying to generate debug information for your code, but it is unable to do so because the "DoNotShip" flag is enabled.

The "DoNotShip" flag is a setting in Unity that is used to optimize the build process and reduce the size of the final executable file. When this flag is enabled, certain debug information and symbols are stripped from the final build, making it smaller and more efficient.

To resolve this error, you can try disabling the "DoNotShip" flag in the Unity Build Settings. To do this, go to File > Build Settings, select the platform you are building for, uncheck the "Development Build" option. This will disable the "DoNotShip" flag and allow the Burst Compiler to generate debug information for your code.

[image]

Please let us know if this fixes your error

Comment: This is not an error. Just debug info generated by the burst compiler. It does not affect building. They are akin to .pdb files from C++. They help make a callstack from a potential crash dump human readable, nothing more. The error is elsewhere. Also as far as I remember, this gets generated in release build as well, this is [not a dev build thing](https://forum.unity.com/threads/burstdebuginformation_donotship-in-builds.1172273/).

Comment: I’ve unchecked the development build box and I’m still receiving the same problem